# What is a typical duty cycle for Bluetooth headsets playing music?

Tags: bluetooth, music

When conducting SAR testing for Bluetooth headsets/earbuds, multiple tests are typically carried out using different types of modulation, all at a “worst case” *i.e.* duty cycle of 100%

What is a typical duty cycle when *e.g.* playing high quality aac encoded music or so, with both devices well within range. I am just looking for a ballpark figure.

Comment: Search And Rescue? Synthetic Aperture Radar?

Comment: Specific absorption rate, tests manditory for FCC (Federal Communications Commission) approval for goods to be sold in the US (United States)

Comment: does this question *really* make sense? Bluetooth can operate at various speeds, so the duty cycle isn't fixed (see Lior's answer), but depends on quality of the channel (especially, on distance, and interference from other devices). Also, Bluetooth devices certainly do *power control*, so that the emitted power isn't fixed, either, but adjusted to the needs of the transmission. So, thinking about *typical* makes little sense to begin with, and it's also irrelevant for health-relevant measurements, since these need to cover expectable worst-cases, not typical ones.

Comment: I am inclined to agree with that, Marcus. I did perhaps not know how to put my thoughts into a good question with a clear answer. As you have pointed out, there are many factors that determine the actual SAR for a user, i.e. a worst case scenario is needed. However, the result of a worst case scenario may be unnecessarily off putting or frightening for a user if the SAR during normal usage were only a very small fraction of worst case. This is what I was wondering about. But given Lior’s answer this is probably not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the RX bandwidth very rough estimate:
We have to assume few assumptions:

1. AAC bitrate is 128Kbps
2. Bluetooth 5 is used.

Bluetooth 5 datarate can be anywhere from 250Kbps to 50Mbps. Lets pick a reasonable 2Mbps, that gives a rough duty cycle of 12.5%. Actual duty cycle will be higher (protocol overhead, network overhead).

TX Bandwidth will be lower than that, it is mainly control and network management frames. Usual keep alive period for a BT device is 1 sec, but it is highly dependent on the device and power saving settings.

Comment: That is interesting. So what determines the data rate that can be achieved? Are higher power and higher transmission speeds correlated? Intuitively for me, I would have assumed that higher signal power only extends the range.

Comment: Link budget, RX sensitivity, Transceiver capabilities, communication standard, modulation are just few of the parameters that dictate possible data rate.  SAR is concerned with Frequency, TX power and duty cycle, all other factors are not really relevant for it.